# I am trying to make an API call to SpaceX, but I keep getting an error on my response. Is my POJO the issue?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, mvvm, pojo

So currently I am trying to make an API call to get launches(https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches) from spacex. I can't tell if the POJO was generated incorrectly. For some reason I keep getting this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.spacex, PID: 13481
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

But when I do an API call to get the latest launch I get an actual response

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1418ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=15042096638405, Vsync=15043479971683, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15043493004500, AnimationStart=15043493189900, PerformTraversalsStart=15043494154700, DrawStart=15043498745100, SyncQueued=15043501592400, SyncStart=15043502485000, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15043502592300, SwapBuffers=15043503508300, FrameCompleted=15043516419500, DequeueBufferDuration=921000, QueueBufferDuration=671000, 
I/System.out: SpaceXResponse(missionName=CRS-20, staticFireDateUtc=2020-03-01T10:20:00.000Z, launchYear=2020, launchDateUtc=2020-03-07T04:50:31.000Z, launchFailureDetails=null, flightNumber=91, isTentative=false, rocket=Rocket(secondStage=SecondStage(payloads=[PayloadsItem(payloadType=Dragon 1.1, payloadMassKg=1977.0, payloadId=CRS-20, nationality=United States, noradId=[], customers=[NASA (CRS)], orbit=ISS, orbitParams=OrbitParams(periapsisKm=null, meanAnomaly=null, inclinationDeg=null, regime=low-earth, argOfPericenter=null, eccentricity=null, apoapsisKm=null, semiMajorAxisKm=null, raan=null, epoch=null, lifespanYears=null, referenceSystem=geocentric, periodMin=null, meanMotion=null, longitude=null), payloadMassLbs=4358.539, reused=true, manufacturer=SpaceX)], block=5.0), rocketId=falcon9, firstStage=FirstStage(cores=[CoresItem(flight=2, landingType=RTLS, gridfins=true, landingIntent=true, legs=true, landSuccess=true, landingVehicle=LZ-1, block=5.0, reused=true, coreSerial=B1059)]), rocketType=FT, rocketName=Falcon 9, fairings=null), missionId=[EE86F74], launchWindow=0, crew=null, launchDateLocal=2020-03-06T23:50:31-05:00, tentativeMaxPrecision=hour, ships=[], launchDateUnix=1583556631, launchSuccess=true, staticFireDateUnix=1583058000, tbd=false, timeline=null, telemetry=Telemetry(flightClub=null), links=Links(missionPatchSmall=https://i.imgur.com/LIrgTnt.png, missionPatch=https://i.imgur.com/LIrgTnt.png, videoLink=https://youtu.be/1MkcWK2PnsU, flickrImages=[], redditRecovery=null, redditMedia=null, redditCampaign=https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/ezn6n0/crs20_launch_campaign_thread, wikipedia=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_CRS-20, redditLaunch=https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/fe8pcj/rspacex_crs20_official_launch_discussion_updates/, youtubeId=1MkcWK2PnsU, presskit=https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/crs-20_mission_press_kit.pdf, articleLink=null), details=SpaceX's 20th and final Crew Resupply Mission under the original NASA CRS contract, this mission brings essential supplies to the International Space Station using SpaceX's reusable Dragon spacecraft. It is the last scheduled flight of a Dragon 1 capsule. (CRS-21 and up under the new Commercial Resupply Services 2 contract will use Dragon 2.) The external payload for this mission is the Bartolomeo ISS external payload hosting platform. Falcon 9 and Dragon will launch from SLC-40, Cape Canaveral Air Force Station and the booster will land at LZ-1. The mission will be complete with return and recovery of the Dragon capsule and down cargo., launchSite=LaunchSite(siteName=CCAFS SLC 40, siteId=ccafs_slc_40, siteNameLong=Cape Canaveral Air Force Station Space Launch Complex 40), upcoming=false)
```

This is my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val spaceRepo : Repository = Repository(SpaceService.spaceApi)
    val spaceLiveData = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
        val data = spaceRepo.getLaunch()
        emit(data)
        println(data)
    }
}
```

This is my Repository

```
class Repository(private val apiInterface : SpaceXInterface) {
    suspend fun getLaunch() = apiInterface.fetchLaunches()
}
```

This is my Service

```
object SpaceService{

   private const val BASE_URL : String = "https://api.spacexdata.com/"

   private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
      .build()

   val spaceApi: SpaceXInterface = retrofit.create(SpaceXInterface::class.java)
}
```

This is my Interface

```
interface SpaceXInterface {

    @GET("v3/launches/latest")
    suspend fun fetchLaunches() : SpaceXResponse

}
```

And this is my Response POJO

```
data class SpaceXResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("mission_name")
    val missionName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("static_fire_date_utc")
    val staticFireDateUtc: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_year")
    val launchYear: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_date_utc")
    val launchDateUtc: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_failure_details")
    val launchFailureDetails: LaunchFailureDetails? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("flight_number")
    val flightNumber: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("is_tentative")
    val isTentative: Boolean? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("rocket")
    val rocket: Rocket? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("mission_id")
    val missionId: List<Any?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_window")
    val launchWindow: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("crew")
    val crew: Any? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_date_local")
    val launchDateLocal: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("tentative_max_precision")
    val tentativeMaxPrecision: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("ships")
    val ships: List<Any?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_date_unix")
    val launchDateUnix: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_success")
    val launchSuccess: Boolean? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("static_fire_date_unix")
    val staticFireDateUnix: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("tbd")
    val tbd: Boolean? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("timeline")
    val timeline: Timeline? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("telemetry")
    val telemetry: Telemetry? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("links")
    val links: Links? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("details")
    val details: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("launch_site")
    val launchSite: LaunchSite? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("upcoming")
    val upcoming: Boolean? = null
)
```

Comment: `I can't tell if the POJO was generated incorrectly.` if you're getting `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY ` then yes, your model is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that its returning a list not an object, You should change your call

```
interface SpaceXInterface {
    @GET("v3/launches/latest")
    suspend fun fetchLaunches() : List<SpaceXResponse>
}
```

And change other parts accordingly.